# Displaying post publish date PHP wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, date

I'm trying to display a posts publish date for posts that **are not** in a particular category.

I think I've the category bit nailed but am struggling on what should be the easy part: the published date.

Currently this is what I have, which returns an error;

```
<?php 
if ( !in_category( array( 'galleries', 'museums', 'cinema', 'bars-clubs', 'restaurant-
cafes' ) )) {
$the_date('F j, Y');
} ?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple mistake, remove $

```
<?php 
if ( !in_category( array( 'galleries', 'museums', 'cinema', 'bars-clubs', 'restaurant-cafes' ))){
the_date('F j, Y');
}
?>
```